# Get all To: emails in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I sent an email to a fair few amount of people and need to send another one to those same people.

I know I can just open the email in a new window and just write out the tos, but it seems pretty inefficient. Is there a way in Thunderbird where I can just send an email to every to: email address?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibly simple answer:

Select the previous email, then...
use "Reply to all" to initiate the email.

Comment: oh damn, that's so beautifully simple... I wish Thunderbird had a right-click action for it but I guess this works. Thank you ::)